# Position fixed covering subsequent table rows (via ng-repeat)

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm working on a project and have been asked to make the first row of the table fixed. They have essentially created a unique first row in the ng-repeat with a controller as seen below (the controller assigns headings such as brand, address, name, etc.):

```
<table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td ng-repeat="thead in resultHeader">
                        <a href="" ng-click="order(thead.line)">{{thead.head}}</a>
                        <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === thead.line" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="line in model.resultList | orderBy:predicate:reverse | limitTo:model.pageSize:model.beginFrom">
                    <td>{{line.brand}}</td>
                    <td>{{line.rep}}<span ng-hide="line.rep=='' || line.rep_name==''">-</span>{{line.rep_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{line.soldto}}</td>
                    <td>{{line.soldto_status}}</td>
                    <td>{{line.credit_status}}</td>
                    <td>{{line.shipto}}</td>
                    <td>{{line.name}}</td>
                    ...
                </tr>
            </table>
```

The first row I can fix without issue utilizing position fixed, however trying to add padding to only the second row is not working: table tr:nth-child(2) {...}.

How can I force all of the subsequent rows downwards in this context?

Comment: It is quite impossible to help with your CSS if you're not including it in the question.

Comment: @Roope the only css worth noting is 'table tr:first-child { position: fixed; }'. This keeps the first row fixed, but adding padding to the second row via 'table tr:nth-child(2) { padding-top: 35px }' does not result in any changes.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle with it?

Answer (score 0):

This would depend on how you want to go about formatting your table, but you could just push down the items still in flow with a padding to `<table>`.

```
table {
  padding-top: 22px;
}
table tr:first-child {
  position: fixed;
  height: 20px;
}
```

Notice, we're not setting anything to subsequent `tr` siblings.

However, depending on your first row height, you'd need to set the padding with some JS, as there's no way to dynamically get that info in CSS.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var h = $('table tr:first-child').height();
  $('table').css('padding-top', h);
});
```

Additionally, `position: fixed;` positions elements relative to the window, whereas `position: absolute;` positions relative to the closest parent container  set to `position: relative;`.  I don't know your reason for fixing the first row, which is presumable a header, to the window, but you may want to consider the following:

```
table {
  position: fixed;
  padding-top: 22px;
}
table tr:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L5eu0vax/